# How do I implement a function that calls specific column names on a list of data frames in R? Error with lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, function, matrix, lapply

I'm pretty new to R. I want to use a function that executes multiple calculations, these calculate across columns in a data frame and creates new columns that hold the final calculations. I want to implement this function across a list of data frames, however, when I try to use lapply I receive an error that states the first column name is missing with no default.

I know this must be an issue with how I am formatting my function, however I am struggling to come up with a solution for this. How can I proceed?

```
#create example data frames, my real data frames are named similarly, with an identical names and a unique id (i.e. example_df_uniqueidnumber), each data frame has columns named identically

df1 <- data.frame(pt1_X = c(1,2,3), pt2_X = c(1,2,3), pt1_Y = c(1,2,3), pt2_Y =c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(pt1_X = c(1,2,3), pt2_X = c(1,2,3), pt1_Y = c(1,2,3), pt2_Y =c(1,2,3))


#create my example function
#NOTE: I call the data "data" (instead of df1 or df2), because I am unsure of what to use instead, as each file name is different due to the unique identifier 

calculate_angles1 <- function(data, pt1_X, pt1_Y, pt2_X, pt2_Y) {
  data$Mx <- (data[[pt1_X]] - data[[pt2_X]])
  data$My <- (data[[pt1_Y]] - data[[pt2_Y]])
    return(data)
}

#create my list of data frames
new_list <- list(df1, df2)


#use lapply to attempt to apply my function to my list of data frames 
AoA <- lapply(new_list, calculate_angles1)
```

After I run my lapply function, I receive this error message..

```
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  argument "pt1_X" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your function is that the name must be surrounded by double quotes. Also to treat the variable values use a single `[` instead of double `[[`.
So the function could be rewritten as:

```
 calculate_angles1 <- function(data) {
  data["Mx"] <- data["pt1_X"] - data["pt2_X"]
  data["My"] <- data["pt1_Y"] - data["pt2_Y"]
  data.frame(data)
}
```

To apply your function to list of dataframes there are various ways `lapply` as you mentioned:

**lapply**

```
 new_list <- lapply(new_list,  calculate_angles1)
```

or using `map()` function from `purrr` package or `tidyverse` family and I think this would be more straightforward. As your function is `Data frame function` it take a data frame as the first argument and returns  data frame. So, you can call `dplyr` verbs to manipulate your data inside `map` as I did here, i.e calling `mutate()` from `dplyr` to create new variables.

**map**

```
library(tidyverse)
new_list <- map(new_list, ~ mutate(.x, Mx=pt1_X-pt2_X, My=pt1_Y-pt2_Y))
```

Both of these options produce same output:

```
> new_list
[[1]]
  pt1_X pt2_X pt1_Y pt2_Y Mx My
1     1     1     1     1  0  0
2     2     2     2     2  0  0
3     3     3     3     3  0  0

[[2]]
  pt1_X pt2_X pt1_Y pt2_Y Mx My
1     1     1     1     1  0  0
2     2     2     2     2  0  0
3     3     3     3     3  0  0
```

Comment: There is nearly never any point in asking why someone downvoted. If they planned to tell you they would have done, and otherwise they will have long gone, and they won't see your enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

new_list <- list(df1, df2)

map(new_list, \(x) {
  x <- x %>% mutate(mx=pt1_X-pt2_X, my=pt1_Y-pt2_Y)
  return(x)
})


[[1]]
  pt1_X pt2_X pt1_Y pt2_Y mx my
1     1     1     1     1  0  0
2     2     2     2     2  0  0
3     3     3     3     3  0  0

[[2]]
  pt1_X pt2_X pt1_Y pt2_Y mx my
1     1     1     1     1  0  0
2     2     2     2     2  0  0
3     3     3     3     3  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `calculate_angles2`, you need to quote the column names:

```
calculate_angles2(df1, 'pt1_X', 'pt2_X', 'pt1_Y', 'pt2_Y')
```

Or, if you insist on using unquoted names, you can do so in base R:

```
calculate_angles3 <- function(data, a, b, c, d){
  data$Mx <- eval(substitute(a-b), data)
  data$My <- eval(substitute(c-d), data)
  data
}

calculate_angles3(df1, pt1_X, pt2_X, pt1_Y, pt2_Y)
```

(or use the [additional functionality for *non standard evaluation*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#quasi-motivation) provided by {rlang})

Answer (score 0):

Start from here:

```
calculate_angles1 <- function(data) {
  Mx <- data[, "pt1_X"] - data[, "pt2_X"]
  My <- data[, "pt1_Y"] - data[, "pt2_Y"]
  do.call("cbind", list(data, "Mx" = Mx, "My" = My))
}

lapply(new_list, calculate_angles1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your function to include a bunch of other parameters that you weren't supplying with `lapply` and had no default values defined. You can make things easier by just changing your `calculate_angles1` function.

```
calculate_angles1 <- function(data) {
  data$Mx <- (data$pt1_X - data$pt2_X)
  data$My <- (data$pt1_Y - data$pt2_Y)
  return(data)
}
```

When you call `data[[pt1_X]]`, R looks for a variable named `pt1_X` to get column information. If you did `pt1_X <- "pt2_Y"` and ran `df1[[pt1_X]]` you'd see you get the "pt2_Y" column, not "pt1_X". That's different than `data$pt1_X` which extracts the `pt1_X` column from the data.frame.